# How to set the inactivate tab in JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have window with 6 Horizontal tabs

The tabs are depended as follows

1. Window

   - Tab 1

     - Tab 2

       - Tab 3
     - Tab 2

       - Tab 3
   - Tab 1

(Assume 1,2,3 are tab indexes).

I am preparing different windows with different levels of tabs dynamically based on the requirement.

Now as per the my requirement I need to show tabs `currentIndex+1` and below index tabs as active mode and remain tabs should be look like inactivated tabs. When user clicking on the `currentIndex+2` or more index tab at that I am handling with error message, like you need to fill up some more tabs data. but before that user should know by viewing tab.

(All Tabs are should viewable based if user in Tab 1 then tab 3 should be look like inactivated mode )

What code I need to write in following logic. Please guide me.

```
for ( Integer i : tabIndexs) {
    if ( currentIndex+1 < i  )  {
        ????????????
        ????????????    
    }
}
```

Comment: Start by taking a look at [`JTabbedPane#setEnabledAt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#setEnabledAt%28int,%20boolean%29)

Comment: no idea what you are trying to do ... but as already noted in your other question: JTabbedPane allows only very rudimentary control about the tab placement.

Comment: Also consider [`Outline`](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/4447).

Comment: @MadProgrammer I followed your hint, it working perfectly, But this feature is showing as * (multiply symbol). Is it possible to change the view? instead of showing * I need to show as inactive (I mean applying styles )

Comment: @Giri A more complicated solution would involve supplying your own tab renderers and selection model.  Check out [How to use tabbed panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html) for some more details